# Accessing multidimensional matrices in python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
sumc=0
t = int(input())
while t :
    x = input().split()
    n = int(x[0])
    k = int(x[1])
    e = int(x[2])
    m = int(x[3])
    suma = [0]*(n-1)
    Matrix = []
    for i in range(n-1):
        Matrix.append([])
        for j in range(e):
            p = int(input())
            Matrix[i].append(p)
    for i in range(n-1):
        for j in range(e):
            suma[i] = suma[i] + Matrix[i][j]
    for j in range(e):
        p = int(input())
        Matrix[n-1][j].append(p)
    suma.sort(suma,suma+(n-1))
    for j in range(e-1):
        sumc  = sumc + Matrix[n-1][j]
    for z in range(m+1):
        if(suma[k-1] < sumc+z):
            break
    if (z==m+1):
        print("imposible")
    else:
        arr[n-1][e-1] = z
        print(arr[n-1][e-1])
    t-=1
```

I want to access array by keeping one parameter/row/column (here row represented by (n-1), in line 21) constant. But getting error "index out of range".
In general, how to access arrays for such type of problems where one of the parameters is/are constant.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/untitled/cde_chf_entexam.py", line 21, in <module>
    Matrix[n-1][j].append(p)
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

JUST SEE THE LINE 20-21 FOR THE ERROR, WHOLE CODE IS NOT NECESSARY, IT'S POSTED IF IT MIGHT HELP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop:

```
for i in range(n-1):
    Matrix.append([])
    for j in range(e):
        p = int(input())
        Matrix[i].append(p)
```

adds `n-1` elements to `Matrix`.  Since python is 0 indexed, this means that the highest index in `Matrix` is `n-2`.

When you do: `Matrix[n-1][j].append(p)`, the expression `Matrix[n-1]` will fail with an `IndexError` because `n-1` is one higher than the highest indexible location (`n-2`).

---

As an aside, lists of lists are valid data structures for storing matrices in pure python, but there are 3rd party libraries dedicated to making matrices easier to work with.  The de-facto standard in this area is `numpy`.